# Multiple optional query parameters with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-design, parameters, many-to-many, query-performance

I use PostgreSQL10 and I want to built queries that have multiple optional parameters.

A user must input area name, but then it is optional to pick none or any combination of the following
 event, event date, category, category date, style

So a full query could be "all the banks (category), constructed in 1990 (category date) with modern architecture (style), that got renovated in 1992 (event and event date) in the area of NYC (area) ".

My problem is that all those are in different tables, connected by many-to-many tables, so I cannot do something like

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE (Event IS NULL OR Event = event)
```

I dont know if any good will come if I just join four tables. 
I can easily find the area id, since it is required, but I dont know what the user chose, beside that.

Any suggestions on how to approach this, with Postgre?

Thanks
[image]

Comment: You are almost there : `SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT* FROM correlated_tables that_you_want WHERE conditions_that_you_want);`

Answer (score 1):

It might be *optimal* to build the entire query dynamically and only join in tables that you know you're going to need in order to apply the user's filters, but it's impractical. You're better off creating a view on the full set of tables. Use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s to ensure that you don't accidentally filter out valid combinations and index your tables to ensure that the query planner can navigate the table graph quickly. Then query the view with a `WHERE` clause reflecting only the filters you want to apply.

If performance becomes a concern and you don't mind having non-realtime data, you could use a [materialized view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rules-materializedviews.html) to cache the results. Materialized views can be indexed directly, but this is a pretty radical change so don't do this unless you have to.

Comment: Yes, I will use indexes anyway. So, you suggest a view with joins? But this will not prevent the use of `IF`s and the query planner will cache the wrong plan, so next queries will be slower. After some research I believe that dynamic sql is the right thing to do in terms of speed and maintenance. I never used dynamic sql before in practice and I dont have a code yet, but at least in theory, this is the way to go, I believe. Maybe there is a better reason to reject dynamic sql? Please elaborate if so. Thanks

Comment: You don't want conditionals. Get all the data you will ever possibly need and filter it down to what you need in the moment. Think in terms of sets, not iterate-and-evaluate. Views are run dynamically so the query planner will be able to cope. Dynamic SQL is a tool of last resort: it's so complex and fragile that it should be avoided unless there is no other reasonable way to accomplish your goal.

Comment: So, practically, see what user inserted and built the FROM and WHERE clauses accordingly, as strings. Then attach those strings to views and then execute. OK, views run dynamically, but for different parameters every time, since different params are inserted each time.  Or maybe I dont get something. Thanks again

Comment: No: create a view with a consistent `FROM` clause which joins all the tables you will ever need. Then `SELECT * FROM myview WHERE...` and apply your specific filters to the entire dataset. Your `WHERE` clause is the only part that changes.

Comment: Making a view of such query does not fix its speed and maintenance issues, because the WHERE part is still not static. More info [here](https://sqlstudies.com/2017/02/27/queries-with-optional-parameters/), [here](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2005/12/11/optional-parameters-in-the-where-clause/) and [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bartd/2009/05/03/sometimes-the-simplest-solution-isnt-the-best-solution-the-optional-parameter-problem/). Keep in mind that the last example in the last links looks like what u suggested, but is about SQL 2008. I am gonna go with dynamic sql after all